# scss not accepting percentage width

Tags: css, sass

I have an scss file which contains a property width and value `100%`. However, its giving an error while compiling:

```
{ [Error: assets/sass/components/_communities.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "...   width: 100%": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
        on line 25 of assets/sass/components/_communities.scss
        from line 39 of assets/sass/main.scss
>>             width: 100%;
```

**Code:**

```
.communities .communities__logo:nth-child(5) .grid__cell img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

What could be the reason and possible solution?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Seems an error when compiling as SASS and not SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `(100%)` instead of `100%` or you can this function:`percentage(1)`.
It is useful when you want use for example `1/3` as argument of the function is percentage as decimal.

Comment: Was wondering if its a bug in the compiler or an intended way to use percentage?

Comment: This is not valid. Sass does not have any problem compiling that. The error is from compiling as Sass and not as Scss.